# Making an array of data taken from JSON

Tags: python, json, dictionary, watson

I'm trying to run a sentiment analysis on some news article using the News API along with the Watson API. I haven't had much experience working with  JSON and wanted to know a way to pull data from a JSON output.

The News API gives an output like this:

```
{
    status: "ok",
    totalResults: 10,
   -articles: [
       -{
            -source: {
                 id: "bbc-news",
                 name: "BBC News"
             },
             author: "BBC News",
             title: "Casualties in NY apartment block fire",
             description: "Some 15 people are reportedly injured in the 
             blaze near Bronx Zoo in New York.",
             url: "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-42508963",
         }
    ]
}
```

There are more than one articles each with their own source, author, title, etc. I want to be able to extract the Author, Title, Description, and URL and put it in a Dictionary. Then run the URLs through Watson to get a Sentiment Value.

I am able to pull out the status, totalResults, and articles from the JSON but have been unsuccessful in being able to go a layer in and pull out the other article specific information.

End goal is a GUI but thats me getting ahead of myself. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: My bad for not including code. But accepted answer worked so I won't be adding my code since it's kinda irrelevant.

Comment: show us your code

Comment: Without the code and any errors you have, we can't really help fix your problem. Can you give us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample JSON object above, if it is stored in a variable called `response` then you can do this.

```
for article in response['articles']:
    print(article['author'])
    print(article['url'])
```